# asp.net Entity Framework 6.0 - What Context Generator should I be using?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, member

Reworded the question:

I need to upgrade to the 6.0 Entity Framework.  I used the EF 6.x Entity Object Generator to create a new Context.  Now, I get a syntax error.  It seems that the generated code now generates an ObjectContext rather than the newer DBContext.

Here's the code that no longer works.

```
public abstract class Base<T> where T : class {
    public static void save(T entity) {
        using (var context = new DataContext()) {
            context.Entry(entity).Member("Changed_Date").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
            context.Entry(entity).Member("Changed_User").CurrentValue = userId;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: Entry (in the Base class) is now a compile error when used with the generated code.

The DataContext (snippets):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[assembly: EdmSchemaAttribute()]
#region EDM Relationship Metadata

#endregion

namespace DB
{
    public partial class encludeDataContext : ObjectContext
    {
    }
}
```

Which generator should I be using?

Comment: Please post the exact compiler error message!

Comment: Thanks @nemesv:   Error 493 'DataContext' does not contain a definition for 'Entry' and no extension method 'Entry' accepting a first argument of type 'DataContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It's a normal member of `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`, check (and post) the definition of your DataContext.

Comment: Check if your references are pointing to the correct binaries.

Comment: The problem is that the DataContext is 482,160 lines long!  It's the auto generated code from the edmx.  But I've added a snippet to the original post.

Comment: I think it's a normal member of System.Data.Entity.DbContext in EF5 but seems not to be there in EF6.

Comment: AHAH:  by looking more closely at the DataContext, I see that it is inherited from ObjectContext now rather than DBContext. This explains why Entry() is not a member... but does not answer the question, How do you do this in EF6?

Comment: DbContext is a wrapper (decorator) for code-first. Are you sure you were using an EDMX (db/model first) in EF5?

Comment: If you are using EF6 remove the reference to System.Data.Entity.dll to avoid hard to debug errors resulting in using EF5 types in an EF6 app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some decoupling was performed in EF6.

```
public DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
```

is in library  `System.Data.Entity`

`System.Data.Entity` is in BOTH 
 `EntityFramework` and `System.Data`

so becareful with namespaces

```
Context.Entry(entity).Member("Changed_Date").   //.... should be Ok
```

Comment: True dat... I think I've resolved those issues.  It seems I ought to have asked a more clear question... How do I get the generator to create a DBContext rather than an ObjectContext.

Comment: you have a model generated Context. ? So regenerate it under ef6

Comment: I think I'm using the EF 6.x EntityObject Generator.

Comment: im thinking question sample code and title dont match the actual issue.  Should the question be "reworked"?

Comment: I think you comments have led me closer to the real problem... I have probably used the wrong Context generator and should be using something else like Reverse POCO or CodeFirst.

Comment: well i cant comment on that, I have no idea what youre up to. Model first / Codefirst / DB first.   And what this 482K long file is. Nor what generated it.